# How do I translate <b> tags inside data with xsl-fo

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I have report that I must convert to PDF using xsl-fo from xml data coming from a MySQL database.

The xml structure that I am working on has already been used to create a HTML report.

There are certain fields that already have html tags inside that I was able to use in the HTML report by adding disable-output-escaping="yes" to my xsl:value-of's statement.

How do I do the similar operation in xsl-fo?  Is there a way I can change the  tags to be fo:inline?  Or perhaps something I can change in the database output that will be the equivalent PDF version of bolding?

Here is a xml snippet:

```
<foal_line>
  <yob>0</yob> 
  <description>Tis The Alarm. Unplaced at 3 in NA. Dam of <B>SA MOKEN</B> (f, by Smoke Glacken. 2 wins at 2, $60,382 in NA. Won Ken Kendrick Memorial Futurity (SRP, $25,043). 2nd Kachina S. (RUI, $10,982). 3rd Ruidoso Thoroughbred Futurity (RUI, $7,787), etc.) Granddam of <B>Dream Kin</B> (f, by Desert God. 4 wins, 2 to 4, $127,880 in US. 2nd New Mexico Cup Juv. Fillies S.-R (ZIA, $33,440). 3rd C. O. "Ken" Kendrick Memorial S-R (SRP, $7,500), Lincoln H. [R] (RUI, $5,000), Carlos Salazar S. [N] (ALB, $4,000), etc.)</description> 
</foal_line>
```

My previous xslt snippet to create xhtml:

```
<tr>
   <td width="30px" style="vertical-align:text-top;">
  <xsl:value-of select="yob"/>
   </td>
   <td style="vertical-align:text-top;text-align:left;padding-left:2px">
  <xsl:value-of select="description" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
   </td>
</tr>
```

My current xsl-fo snippet:

```
<fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-cell>
       <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="yob"/></fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell>
       <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="description"/></fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
```

**Edit:**
Here is what I'm really getting from the server.  That's what I get for using IE to view my xml.

```
<foal_line>
  <yob>0</yob> 
  <description>Tis The Alarm. Unplaced at 3 in NA. Dam of &lt;B&gt;SA MOKEN&lt;/B&gt; (f, by Smoke Glacken. 2 wins at 2, $60,382 in NA. Won Ken Kendrick Memorial Futurity (SRP, $25,043). 2nd Kachina S. (RUI, $10,982). 3rd Ruidoso Thoroughbred Futurity (RUI, $7,787), etc.) Granddam of &lt;B&gt;Dream Kin&lt;/B&gt; (f, by Desert God. 4 wins, 2 to 4, $127,880 in US. 2nd New Mexico Cup Juv. Fillies S.-R (ZIA, $33,440). 3rd C. O. "Ken" Kendrick Memorial S-R (SRP, $7,500), Lincoln H. [R] (RUI, $5,000), Carlos Salazar S. [N] (ALB, $4,000), etc.)</description> 
</foal_line>
```

This is why suggested answer is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing `xsl:value-of` for `<description>`, do `xsl:apply-templates`. You can then create a template to match `<B>`. In the `B` template you can use `fo:inline` to make the text bold.

Here's an example:

```
  <xsl:template match="foal_line">
    <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="yob"/></fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block><xsl:apply-templates select="description"/></fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="description">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="B">
    <fo:inline font-weight="bold"><xsl:apply-templates/></fo:inline>
  </xsl:template>
```

Using your XML input and the above templates, the following output is generated:

```
<fo:table-row xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <fo:table-cell>
      <fo:block>0</fo:block>
   </fo:table-cell>
   <fo:table-cell>
      <fo:block>Tis The Alarm. Unplaced at 3 in NA. Dam of <fo:inline font-weight="bold">SA MOKEN</fo:inline> (f, by Smoke Glacken. 2 wins at 2, $60,382 in NA. Won Ken Kendrick Memorial Futurity (SRP, $25,043). 2nd Kachina S. (RUI, $10,982). 3rd Ruidoso Thoroughbred Futurity (RUI, $7,787), etc.) Granddam of <fo:inline font-weight="bold">Dream Kin</fo:inline> (f, by Desert God. 4 wins, 2 to 4, $127,880 in US. 2nd New Mexico Cup Juv. Fillies S.-R (ZIA, $33,440). 3rd C. O. "Ken" Kendrick Memorial S-R (SRP, $7,500), Lincoln H. [R] (RUI, $5,000), Carlos Salazar S. [N] (ALB, $4,000), etc.)</fo:block>
   </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
```

Also, you should do the same for `<yob>` if it is also mixed content (text and other elements such as `<B>`).

You can also do this for your XHTML XSLT so you don't have to use `disable-output-escaping` (which I try to avoid at all costs).

Comment: This isn't quite working for me. Using XSLT debugger I can see that it is going into the template match="description" but it is not matching the template for "B".  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think I found my issue.  The raw xml is actually doing escaped brackets. &lt;B&gt; and &lt;/B&gt;  If I manually edit it to proper bold tags it works.

Comment: After coming full circle, I've been able to get DevNull's solution working.  I had convert my Document Object to a string replace the &lt; and &gt; with corresponding non-escaped characters, then re-parse into a Document Object to get the Bold tags to be recognized as nodes.  Then the style sheet was able to replace the <B> with the appropriate FOP bolding.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is rather old. I'm using Apache FOP and got stuck with this behavior of encoded or raw HTML treatment. Here's my solution I've been working on for a couple of hours.

XML:

```
    <foal_line>
        <yob>0</yob> 
        <description><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">HTML text can be <b>bold</b> and <i>italic</i></html></description>
    </foal_line>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 >

    <!--  Output in XML -->
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" />

    <!-- ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ --> 
    <!-- Templates                                                          -->
    <!-- ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ --> 
    <xsl:template match="/">    
        <fo:root>
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="seite" page-width="210mm" page-height="297mm" margin="20mm 20mm 20mm 20mm">
                    <fo:region-body margin="20mm 0mm 10mm 0mm"/>
                    <fo:region-before region-name="header"/>
                    <fo:region-after region-name="footer"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>

            <fo:page-sequence id="seite" master-reference="seite">
                <fo:static-content flow-name="footer">
                    <fo:block>Footer</fo:block>
                </fo:static-content>
                <fo:static-content flow-name="header">
                    <fo:block>Header</fo:block>
                </fo:static-content>
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>         
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="foal_line">
        <fo:block-container>
            <fo:block>Yob: <xsl:value-of select="yob"/></fo:block>
            <fo:block>Desc: 
                <xsl:apply-templates select="description/xhtml:html"/>
            </fo:block>         
        </fo:block-container>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="description">
        <xsl:message>Description</xsl:message>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xhtml:b">
        <xsl:message>Bold</xsl:message>
        <fo:inline font-weight="bold"><xsl:apply-templates/></fo:inline>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xhtml:i">
        <xsl:message>italic</xsl:message>
        <fo:inline font-style="italic"><xsl:apply-templates/></fo:inline>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Finally I got a well-formed FO and could translate that into PDF.